# Read current value of switchpreference

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am using a switch statement to check the origin of the preference.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Display the fragment as the main content.
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
        .commit();
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content,
        new SettingsFragment()).commit();
}

public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    Preference pref = findPreference(key);
    switch(key) {
        case "key_video_quality":
            Log.i("Tag1", "Video quality button pressed");
            break;
        case "key_video_length":
            Log.i("Tag2", "Video length button pressed");
            break;
        case "key_auto_save":
            Log.i("Tag3", "Auto save button pressed");
            break;
        case "key_dark_mode":
            Log.i("Tag4", "Dark mode button pressed");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`key_auto_save` is never triggered, and `key_dark_mode` is, they are both `SwitchPreferences`.

Is there a method to check the current value of switch preference when it is pressed so i can decide to switch on/off a dark theme for my application? As i am using it as a general `Preference` i don't think `isChecked()` applies here.

Also, i'm unsure on the `key_auto_save` problem, the key is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method, in `case "key_dark_mode":` i used `sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);` to return if my `switchPreference` was true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Are you registering the listener `onResume`?

```
getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

It is hard to judge without seeing more code, for example are you extending `PreferenceActivity`?

Comment: Did you register the onChangeListener onResume? paste this after super.onResume() in your fragment `getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);`

Comment: No difference, this also doesn't help me read the value of a switchPreference

Comment: I hear you, the problem is the `key` contains the value that is passed if the fragment detects that settings are changed. If it doesn't work that means the fragment is not aware and no function is calling back `onSharedPreferenceChanged` Sorry registering the listener onResume was the only thing I had in mind.